# openCV-error while copying a part of image from one to other using indexing

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, indexing, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

```
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('/home/niti/Downloads/ironman.jpeg').convert('RGB')

img=cv2.imread('/home/niti/Downloads/ironman.jpeg')

def click(event,x,y,flag,param):# checking coordiantes
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        strp=str(x)+','+str(y)
        font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img,strp,(x,y),font,1,(0,255,255),2)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)

b,g,r=cv2.split(img)
img=cv2.merge((b,g,r))
print(img.shape)        
print(img.size)
print(img.dtype)

hand=img[928:233, 1103:378]

img[71:121, 187:216]=hand 

#cv.imshow('image',img)   

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting the following error

> (774, 1280) 990720 uint8
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        22 hand=img[928:233, 1103:378]
>        23 
>   ---> 24 img[71:121, 187:216]=hand
>        25 
>        26 #cv.imshow('image',img)
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,0,3) into
>   shape (50,29,3)

Comment: It is clear from the error that you are trying to copy a part of an array into another one which doesn't have the correct shape.

Comment: Well...I came to know the reason but is there any way to solve it